# Did I refactor this example from Qt Wiki correctly?

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I found this example on how to catch the press of the Enter key from [Qt Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_catch_enter_key):

```
bool KeyEnterReceiver::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent* key = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if ((key->key() == Qt::Key_Enter) || (key->key() == Qt::Key_Return)) {
            // Enter or return was pressed
        } else {
            return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seemed very cumbersome and I noticed I could refactor it to be a lot simpler:

```
bool KeyEnterReceiver::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        auto* key = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);  // clang-tidy suggested to change static_cast to dynamic_cast
        if ((key->key() == Qt::Key_Enter) || (key->key() == Qt::Key_Return)) {
            // Enter or return was pressed
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Did I miss anything or is my refactoring correct and identically functioning?

Could this be refactored to be even simpler?

Comment: I don't know Qt, but given the code I see a change: you are now calling `eventFilter` when `event->type() != QEvent::KeyPress`. Also, this question sounds more like for this SE: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @R2RT That also happens in the original code.

Comment: @R2RT But doesn't the original code also call the `eventFilter` when `event->type() != QEvent::KeyPress`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is equivalent. In fact, it's better than the original example, which has dead code in it that can never be reached. The `return false;` of the original code is impossible to reach. There is no branching path that can ever lead to it. You eliminated that in your version. You also eliminated the duplicated call to the overridden `eventFilter()`.

The dynamic cast is not needed, because the static cast is guaranteed to be valid since `event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress`.

Anyway, the original code is quite bad, actually. Your version is better.